# Figure out required height of an image, according to the dimension of a box inside that image

Tags: javascript, math, formula

Title gore sorry, it's hard to describe.

I got an image, which is let's say, `1000px` in height. On that image i know the dimensions and position of a box, which is `600px` tall. The box inside scales proportionally to the height of the image. I need to figure out which height i need to set the image to in order to get the height of the box to match `600px`. I can only set the height of the image.

Known variables

```
boxHeight = 800
imageHeight = 1000
desiredBoxHeight = 600
requiredImageHeight = ??
```

Here what i mean: Left, the current situation, right the desired situation.
**Whats the math in order to figure out the height of the image in the right situation?**

I've tried and tried, but i'm not a math person, so i'm at wit's end.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly; The image scales proportionally to the size of the box. The box goes from 800 to 600 pixels. So the image goes from 1000 to 1000 * (600/800) = 750 pixels.

So that's:

```
requiredImageHeight  = imageHeight * (desiredBoxHeight / boxHeight)
```

Comment: Wow, is the math really that simple. I feel so stupid. Thank you so much.